# How to show tool tip at left of text or text field

Tags: html, css

**I want a tool tip in my application on mouse hover. I tried alot bt not getting any result** I'm missing something in my css 
 Html.,

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
      <p>
        <a href="#" data-tooltip="left tooltip" data-placement="left">left tooltip</a>
      </p>

    </div>
```

Someone tell the solution

Css:

```
  body {
      margin: 20px;
    }

    a[data-tooltip] {
      position: relative;
    }
    a[data-tooltip]::before,
    a[data-tooltip]::after {
      position: absolute;
      display: none;
      opacity: 0.85;
    }
    a[data-tooltip]::before {
      /*
       * using data-tooltip instead of title so we 
       * don't have the real tooltip overlapping
       */
      content: attr(data-tooltip);
      background: #000;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 13px;
      padding: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      /* we don't want the text to wrap */
      white-space: nowrap;
      text-decoration: none;

    }

    a[data-tooltip][data-placement="left"]::before {
      top: -25%;
      right: 100%;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
```

I want a tool tip in my application on mouse hover. I tried a lot bt not getting any result

Comment: You might want to use `title` attribute?

Comment: Try to add display: block; in this css 
a[data-tooltip][data-placement="left"]:before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing 2 elements in your CSS (see comments in the following CSS code) :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/wmZ6P/2/)**

*CSS :*

```
a[data-tooltip]:hover::before { /* <- added :hover so it displays only on hover state */
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block; /* <-- this line */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your css

```
a[data-tooltip]:hover::before, a[data-tooltip]:hover::after {
  position: absolute;
    display:inline;
  opacity: 0.85;
}
```

See working demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/Hw3k2/